# Replacing an item in an array with another item in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
  var CutRoadArray = [
            ['Location', '_Location'],
            ['Applicant Info', '_ApplicantInfo'],
            ['Details', '_ApplicationDetails'],
            ['Bond Info', '_BondInfo'],
            ['Attachments', '_Attachments'],
            ['Review', '_ReviewA']
        ];
```

I am trying to replace the last item, with a different entry.

The code I have so far goes like below:

```
                var newreviewElem = ['Review', '_ReviewB'];
                var index = CutRoadArray.lastIndexOf('_ReviewA');
                CutRoadArray.splice(index, 0, newreviewElem);
                console.log(CutRoadArray);
```

This is however not working. What am I doing wrong ?

https://jsfiddle.net/yygLdo0o/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are actually two things wrong with your answer.

The first is that you need to grab the correct index. If you're replacing the last item, just grab the array.length.

The second is that you need to indicate how many you're replacing:

```
CutRoadArray.splice(CutRoadArray.length - 1, 1, newreviewElem);
```

The second argument in splice should be 1, not 0.

This will replace the last element of any size array, because it doesn't rely on an item in the array being in a specific location or a particular index.

`CutRoadArray.length - 1` is grabbing the number of items in the array, but since `splice` uses a zero based index, you have to subtract one to get the index of the last item in the array.

The second argument (bolded below), tells splice to replace a single item.

[Documentation about splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

CutRoadArray.splice(CutRoadArray.length - 1, **1**, newreviewElem);

And then finally, the last argument is the item to actually add to the array.

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yygLdo0o/3/)

Comment: Thank you and yes, this works, can you please explain the  CutRoadArray.splice(CutRoadArray.length - 1, 1, newreviewElem); part so me or anyone else who stumbles across this, would learn ?

Comment: thank you for the array 101, I hope this helps others as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace the element, use

```
CutRoadArray.splice(index, 1, newreviewElem);
```

The second parameter of [splice is the deleteCount](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice), 0 means no item will be removed.

An other problem with your code is that

```
CutRoadArray.lastIndexOf('_ReviewA');
```

will always return -1, as `CutRoadArray` is an array of arrays, meaning every element of it is an array, it doesn't have an element which is `'_ReviewA'`. (That's an element of one of `CutRoadArray`'s elements.)

Comment: What would be the right way to do this. Lets say I have a button or a checkbox, depending on its state, it would alter the element to reviewA or reviewB ?

Comment: @user3067743 it's hard to tell what's the *right* way to do this without knowing more of your use-case. You will probably have to look through all the elements of the array to find one containing your string.

Comment: the part in brackets, (That's an element of one of CutRoadArray's elements.) finally sunk in, your answer was swift and correct, I am accepting Blunderfest's answer only because it has a fiddle, someone wandering into this page could easily try the fiddle. Thank you ...

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
CutRoadArray.splice(index, 1, newreviewElem);
```

The second parameter indicates how many items should be replaced.

Comment: Thank you for your swift help.

Answer (score 1):

Your

```
CutRoadArray.lastIndexOf('_ReviewA');
```

will, of course, not find anything since `CutRoadArray` contains arrays, not strings.

```
for(var iter = 0; iter < CutRoadArray.length; iter++) {
  if (CutRoadArray[iter][1] == '_ReviewA') {
    CutRoadArray[iter] = newreviewElem;
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to iterate over the main array and search in the nested array for the wanted index. After found it is simple to replace the nested array at the index like `array[index] = replace;`. If not found, the the array is pushed to the end.

```js
function replace(array, find, replace) {
    var index;
    if (array.some(function (a, i) {
            if (~a.indexOf(find)) {
                index = i;
                return true;
            }
        })
    ) {
        array[index] = replace;
    } else {
        array.push(replace);
    }
}

var cutRoadArray = [
      ['Location', '_Location'],
      ['Applicant Info', '_ApplicantInfo'],
      ['Details', '_ApplicationDetails'],
      ['Bond Info', '_BondInfo'],
      ['Attachments', '_Attachments'],
      ['Review', '_ReviewA']
];

replace(cutRoadArray, '_ReviewA', ['Review', '_ReviewB']);
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(cutRoadArray, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```